# Editing home page html code in RWD theme

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme

I'm using the RWD theme in the latest Magento CE. I want to edit the homepage only to have a 100% width container within the page content section. I realise I can do this in CSS but it will affect any other element with the same class. How do I go about editing the html for this page only? I presumed it would be in the 1 column phtml - I believe below is the relevant code but I can't see the div class in the content.phtml file either.

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd stick with your first bet, CSS, as it seems you're most comfortable with it.

Magento actually applies a class to every type of page on the site, be it Home Page CMS, Catalog Category, Catalog Product, etc.

For example, your homepage undoubtedly has the following:

`<body class="cms-index-index cms-home">`

Thus, you could target either the body or any element within the body, inclusive only of the homepage, by doing something like this:

```
.cms-home .main {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Just for purposes of comparison, say you want a very narrow product (product pages have a body class of .catalog-product-view) page, you could do something along these lines:

```
.catalog-product-view .main {
    width:680px;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. The issue here is that in RWD the main class is used for multiple elemeets on CMS home and I only want one div to 'break out' and be 100%. I wonder if adding my own <div> element above the php code in my example, for the home page only, would work?

Comment: I wouldn't add a <div>, although that would work as well. Why not add an ID to the element you want to target?

Comment: Also, I'm looking at the RWD theme -- where do you see .main class belonging to more than the single inner content element?

Answer (score 0):

There are few way ,you can do

**By css:** In magento,***a unique class has been*** create for `<body>` tag.
And this `class name` is `cms-index-index`.
 **css work code like:**

```
.cms-index-index .yourDiv {  do your css works}
```

**By set different root template** : *assign different template* file for `root block`  using  `layout xml`.This should be ***replicate of  1column.phtml*** Guss that home page  `root template file` name is `1column-home.phtml`.Do the require change on this template file.

Set this ***template from admin area***. Goto `CMS>Pages>` `Select you cms home page` >then goto it  Design Tab> on field `Layout Update XML` add below code:

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column-home.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Thanks Amit and I understand that element but how would I edit the actual container names that appear on the home page? For example at the moment there is the 'main container' as standard. I cannot see anywhere in the file structure where it's getting those classes from to add them to the divs...